# Tooltips or Popups from List/Reusable Content

Tags: 2013, list, content-editor-web-part, hyperlink

A customer would like to insert descriptions on words in his text on a page.

Two possibilities to show them:

1. You hover a special word and a tooltip shows up with the description of the word.

2. You click a special word and a popup (not new tab or page) shows up with the description

It is possible to add a tooltip text to each link, but we have often same description for many words, this is no solution because you have to update all links everytime something changes.

Would it be possible to show a list item in a popup instead of new tab? Or are there any other solutions for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin for tooltip, like Tooltipster (http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/). Using this, you can provide your content as a jQuery object in the script rather than in the title attribute, using the same description for all texts with same class.

Comment: If I would like to know libraries or programming approach, I would ask at stackoverflow. I am searching for an easy maintainable solution for my customer in sharepoint, which has no programming skills.